# For in statement only prints last results

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I was testing with a command that can view a bot. It will detect the arg and find if the arg is in the thing, if it's in the thing it will print the following information. But, it only works with the last information. How can I fix it?

Command code:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def viewbot(ctx, arg):
            for bot in data['bots']:
                name = bot["name"]
                #createdby = bot["createdby"]
                briefdesc = bot["briefdesc"]
                desc = bot["description"]
                slug = bot["slug"]
            if arg == f'{slug}':
                embed = discord.Embed(title=name,description=briefdesc,timestamp=ctx.message.created_at,colour=discord.Color.dark_green())
                await ctx.send(embed = embed)
            else:
                print("no")
```

JSON Code:

```
{
    "bots": [
        {
            "name": "Bot1",
            "createdby": "Bit#0258",
            "briefdesc": "Texts.",
            "description": "Test",
            "library": "discord.py",
            "slug": "bot1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Bot2",
            "createdby": "BotTest#0001",
            "briefdesc": "Text",
            "description": "Rext",
            "library": "discord.js",
            "slug": "bot2"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you know how to fix it please reply to this question. Thanks.

Comment: What does it mean the "last information"? Also how you call your function?

Comment: Is that actually how your code is indented? Then think carefully: how many times should the `if arg == f'{slug}':` check happen? How many times does it actually happen? What is the feature of your code intended to make it happen that many times? Considering the indentation of your code, will it do as you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your logic:

```
        for bot in data['bots']:
            name = bot["name"]
            #createdby = bot["createdby"]
            briefdesc = bot["briefdesc"]
            desc = bot["description"]
            slug = bot["slug"]

        if arg == f'{slug}':
            ...
```

You *specifically* told it to go through all of the available bots, extract their fields, and write each over the top of the previous set of data.  When you leave the loop, only the most recent value is in each variable.  This is how variables work.

To get all of the values, either move your processing (the `if`) inside the loop, or gather the data in lists instead of scalar variables.